# How do you remove the 1m by 1m gap polygons such as the one at the lower right corner?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, remove

[image]

How do I remove the 1m by 1m polygon in the lower right corner?

I am using ArcMap 10.4 and its Raster calculator.

Comment: Is it a separate feature or the same as the larger blue polygon?  What have you tried?  Does a Select and Delete not work?

Comment: I'm confused about whether you are using vector (you mention polygon) or raster (you mention raster calculator) data.